# Creating Linked List as a Template: Is my implementation correct?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, templates, linked-list

Please have a look at the following diagram

[image]

This is how I implemented it

```
template <typename T>

class LinkedList
{

    struct Link {
    T data;
    struct Link *next;

    public:
    T *first;
  };



LinkedList::LinkedList(void)
{
    first = 0;
}


LinkedList::~LinkedList(void)
{
}

bool LinkedList::IsEmpty()
{
    return (first==0);
}

void LinkedList::Insert(Link *newLink)
{
    newLink->next = first;
    first = newLink;
}

void LinkedList::Display()
{
    Link *current = first;

    while(current!=0)
    {
        current->Display();
        current = current->next;
    }
}

T *LinkedList::Find(int value)
{
    Link *current = first;

    while(current->GetData()!=value)
    {
        if(current->next==0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            current = current->next;
        }
    }

    return current;
}

T *LinkedList::Delete(const int id)
{
    Link *current = first;
    Link *previous = first;

    while(current->GetData()!=id)
    {
        if(current->next==0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            previous = current;
            current = current->next;
        }
    }

    if(current==first)
    {
        first = first->next;
    }
    else
    {
        previous->next = current->next;
    }

    return current;
}
};
```

I do not feel comfortable about my implementation. Specially, I have no idea about what to do inside the `insert()` method, using `T` type.

Following is the diagram for another class, it's `next` pointer is Weapons represent links within a linked list. I doubted whether this is the "Link" class as well. Next is a pointer to the next weapon in the list. I posted it here if it affects the above code.

[image]

How to deal inside the `insert()` method? Apart from that, is my Linked List correct? First time with templates for Linked Lists anyway. Please help!

**NOTE: BUILT IN DATA STRUCTURES ARE NOT ALLOWED. THAT IS WHY I POSTED THE DIAGRAM OF CLASSES. IF I NEED BUILT IN DATASTRUCTURE SUPPORT, THEN I AM NOT ASKING HOW TO BUILD THE CODE BY MY SELF.**

Comment: Why not use one of the many linked list implementations available?

Comment: If possible, use `std::list` or other standard library containers unless if there's a really good reason not to do so.

Comment: @ddriver: nono, need to do it by my self

Comment: @MarkGarcia: no, need to do by my self

Comment: Your insert routine does not take a T* parameter. I think my most pressing question is: Are Link objects supposed to be instantiated by client-code or by the LinkedList?

Comment: @S.C.Madsen: It does right? it is clearly displayed in class diagrams

Comment: @Yohan: I was referring to your code.

Answer (score 0):

**The question I would rather answer:**

My particular problem / exercise is ....

How do I solve my problem using `std::list` or some other standard library container, which will probably use less lines, be easier to understand, be more efficient and help me achieve more as a programmer?

**The unspoken question I'm trying hard not to answer:**

What is wrong with my code?

**The question I think you are actually asking:**

How can I fix my `insert()` method?

**Answer to the last question only:**

It seems like you are trying to append the new link onto the front of the list. Conceptually I would be appending it to the back of the list, but hey, each to his own.

The rub is in the types: Inside your class, the type of your `first` is `T *`, where `T` might be some custom class that implements `GetData()`. So `first` points to a `T`, it should probably point to a `Link` which points to a `T`.

Then your `insert()` method makes a bit more sense.

Still, it is really hard to know if your code is correct without a compliable piece of code, which has a defined predicted output. At least with the standard library you can always assume that if there is a problem, it is not in the linked list implementation.

Do you need to do it yourself because it is homework?